# Why KeyDown event is not working with datagridview c#?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and using windows forms.

I was looking for an event to use with `datagridview` when arrow down key in the keyboard is pressed and I found keyDown `datagridview` event.

What I am trying to do is:

let's say I have `datagridview` with 4 `rows`, now when I press arrow down (in the keyboard) I want the highlight (selection) go down and on same time when a row is selected I want the event to check if the row font color is red or not so I used the following code:

```
 private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {

        int RowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;


        if (dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor == Color.Red)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This row font is red");
        }               


 }
```

When I tried this code it does not work well, the problem is:

Say:

`Row0 font color = black`

`Row1 font color = red`

`Row2 font color = black`

`Row3 font color = black`

Now the selected row is `Row0`, press arrow down it goes to `Row1` but the event doesn't  get fired.  Now the selected row is `Row1` and when I press arrow down the event works but too late, I mean it should get fired when `Row1` is selected.

Anyone knows how can I fix it (or any other ideas)? I just want to check rows font color when I press arrow key down in keyboard?  Thank you

Comment: Is your dgv ever in edit mode? Also try to avoid a combination of keyboard interactivity and messagebox! Is there any relation between RI and RowIndex? What SelectionMode do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event fires **before** the selection actually has changed.

> Key events occur in the following order:
>
> ```
> KeyDown
>
> KeyPress
>
> KeyUp
> ```

So a simple solution is to move your code to the `KeyUp` event, which happens **after** the new row selection has happened.

Answer (score 1):

to achieve this you can use **SelectionChanged** event
first set the row selection mode with following line

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

then here is the selection changed event mechanism

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int RowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor == Color.Black)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This row font is Black");
            }      
        }
    }
```